# Nav bar won't take up all of width on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a nav bar which takes up all the width on desktop, but on mobile it doesn't

HTML:

```
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dev Log</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Credits</a></li>
      
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
  body, html {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #7AE7C7;
  text-align: center;
}

nav{
  background-color: #0b4e2d;
  font-size:18px;
  padding:6px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

ul a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I tried using 100% width and 100% vw on the nav and ul but it didn't work. It seems to only happen when an element is under it

Comment: Your code has several errors: 1. your HTML that you provided is incomplete. There's no opening `<nav>` tag, no opening `<a>` tags. 2. By default, `nav` elements are block level, so will be 100% of the viewport. 3. `margin` should simply be `0` on the `html, body` selectors. 4. Are you sure you aren't seeing the `gap` on the `li` elements? 5. We probably need more code since the question states _It seems to only happen when an element is under it_

Comment: That's my bad. I didn't copy and paste it right

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything wrong, but I have cleaned it up a bit.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #7AE7C7;
}

nav {
  background-color: #0b4e2d;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Dev Log</a>
  <a href="#">Credits</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in your code you're trying to make the elements in the nav take up the whole width.
Firstly, it's more preferable to use Width: 100% in your nav's css.
Secondly, you should restructure your css code properly, the position property should be on top, because css also assigns styles in a particular order, so it's best to put some css properties before another, in order for the styles to be added properly e.g

```
ul {
    position: relative; /*Position comes first*\
    width: 100%; /* Followed by width and height or one of them */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    color: white
      }
}
```

/* This is just an example of a nicely structured css code */

Now to mainly fix the issue: If your nav element, which is the parent, has a width of 100%, the ul will also be restricted to the width of its parent element, so if your nav element has a with of 90%, and you set the width of the ul to 100%, it will take the full 90% of its parent and not 100% of the page because it's restricted to it's parent in normal scenarios, I'm just clearing the air on this issue first.
Now, to set the elements in ul to take the full width, since display:  flex; is already called, you'd just assign justify-content: center; in the ul's styling, after the flex-wrap: wrap; style, this makes the elements move the center of the page on any device, given the width is already set to 100% and then you'd give spacing to them using gap, padding, margin etc.., you could also use justify-content: space-between; to automatically give equal spacing between the elements in ul without having to really set a gap or margin.

```
CSS
nav{
        background-color: #0b4e2d;
        font-size:18px;
        padding:6px;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      ul {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center; /* or space-between */
        align-items: center;
        list-style: none;
        gap: 50px;
        color: white;
        /*margin-left: 15px;*/
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      }
.../* remaining code remains the same*/
```

Comment: It centered the text but the same issue happened

Comment: Re _you should restructure your css code properly_: that's just style (as in code style) and structure. Unless you set the same property twice -- or properties that override each other, such as longhands and shorthands -- in a single ruleset, there is no functional difference. _css also assigns styles in a particular order_: I'm not sure what you're meaning by this.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes it's not really a big issue, I just meant that styles should be assigned a bit better, because it happened that when I set a style of an element once, it didn't work, I then had to change the position of that styling, and then it worked. I was just giving that opinion to avoid bugs . Like now, it's more common for developers to assing the position property style first when giving the style of an element, it could just be a common practice though